# Enviar e-mail com anexo em PHP

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Olá, estou usando o seguinte código:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Enviar e-mail com anexo</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="?acao=enviar" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <table width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
   <tr>
     <td align="right">Nome:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="right">Assunto:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="assunto" id="assunto" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="right">Mensagem:</td>
     <td><textarea name="mensagem" id="mensagem" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="right">Anexo:</td>
     <td><input type="file" id="arquivo" name="arquivo" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Enviar" /></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
</form>

<?php
if ($_POST['acao'] == 'enviar'){
 $nome      = $_POST['nome'];
 $assunto   = $_POST['assunto'];
 $mensagem  = $_POST['mensagem'];
 $arquivo   = $_FILES["arquivo"];

 $corpoMSG = "<strong>Nome:</strong> $nome<br> <strong>Mensagem:</strong> $mensagem";
 // chamada da classe       
 require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
 // instanciando a classe
 $mail   = new PHPMailer();
 // email do remetente
 $mail->SetFrom('email@gmail.com', 'remetente');
 // email do destinatario
 $address = "email2@gmail.com";
 $mail->AddAddress($address, "destinatario");
 // assunto da mensagem
 $mail->Subject = $assunto;
 // corpo da mensagem
 $mail->MsgHTML($corpoMSG);
 // anexar arquivo
 $mail->AddAttachment($arquivo['tmp_name'], $arquivo['name']  );

 if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo "Erro: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
   echo "Mensagem enviada com sucesso!";
  }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

E estou recendo o seguinte erro:

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: ?acao in C:\wamp\www\EMAILL\email.php on line 33
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0050  390248  {main}( )   ...\email.php:0

Realmente não entendo o porque,já dei uma estuda no código mas não consigo entender o erro. Alguém me ajuda, por favor!

Answer (score 0):

O problema é mais simples do que imaginei, no momento em que a página é carregada pela primeira vez as variáveis de requisição $_POST, $_GET e $_REQUEST estão presentes porém não possuem valores definidos. Por isso uma verificação direta a  `$_POST['acao'] == 'enviar'` irá gerar erro por esse motivo deve ser feita antes a verificação `isset($_POST["acao"])`.

Também remova a string de consulta, `?acao=enviar` de atributo `action` do `<form>` e envie a consulta como `input type='hidden'`:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Enviar e-mail com anexo</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="enviar" />
   <table width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
   <tr>
     <td align="right">Nome:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="right">Assunto:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="assunto" id="assunto" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="right">Mensagem:</td>
     <td><textarea name="mensagem" id="mensagem" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="right">Anexo:</td>
     <td><input type="file" id="arquivo" name="arquivo" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Enviar" /></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
</form>

<?php
//
if (isset($_POST["acao"]) && $_POST['acao'] == 'enviar'){
 $nome      = $_POST['nome'];
 $assunto   = $_POST['assunto'];
 $mensagem  = $_POST['mensagem'];
 $arquivo   = $_FILES["arquivo"];

 $corpoMSG = "<strong>Nome:</strong> $nome<br> <strong>Mensagem:</strong> $mensagem";
 // chamada da classe       
 require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
 // instanciando a classe
 $mail   = new PHPMailer();
 // email do remetente
 $mail->SetFrom('email@gmail.com', 'remetente');
 // email do destinatario
 $address = "email2@gmail.com";
 $mail->AddAddress($address, "destinatario");
 // assunto da mensagem
 $mail->Subject = $assunto;
 // corpo da mensagem
 $mail->MsgHTML($corpoMSG);
 // anexar arquivo
 $mail->AddAttachment($arquivo['tmp_name'], $arquivo['name']  );

 if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo "Erro: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
   echo "Mensagem enviada com sucesso!";
  }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bom dia! Eu tentei realizar a alteração porém não obtive nenhum resultado, ele continua retornando as mesmas mensagens de erro.

Comment: Apenas uma, no <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="?acao=enviar" enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Esse trecho que eu postei é todo o meu código.

Comment: O mesmo erro :/

Comment: Continua retornando o mesmo erro: Notice: Undefined index: acao in C:\wamp\www\EMAILL\anexo.php on line 33

Comment: Todo o código em php?

Comment: o erro não persiste

Comment: Você pode me recomendar algum código que tenha a mesma função? Eu realmente preciso disso pra um trabalho de escola.

Comment: Sim, exatamente

Comment: Desculpe-me, a falha é minha! Eu deveria ter percebido esse erro só de bater o olho. Apaguei os comentários pois fica elencada uma discussão longa que não faz mais sentido.